# How to set header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK") for HTTPS protocol in my php api?

Tags: php, api, rest, http, https

I want to display an OK message to my client-side application. when setting set header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK") in HTTP API then it is working fine but it doesn't work over HTTPS. client-side is not receiving the OK message. please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: For both HTTP and HTTPS setting the 200 OK status will work the same. If HTTPS is not working it's not due to that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something specific in the "reason phrase". This is unlikely to be a good idea, because it does not exist in HTTP/2.

The correct approach is just to check the status code.

Comment: yes you are right but I checked using GitHub sample API it is also using HTTPS and I am receiving OK with that.